# Using the SharpSVN api are there any methods available to get the number of lines contained in a file at a Revision without Exporting it?

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

I was just wondering if I missed anything inside the documentation that would allow me to get the number of lines contained in a file at a certain revision (or even number of lines changed from a SvnChangeItem, that would be nice too) without having to directly export the file to the filesystem and parse through it counting each line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, your stuck with exactly the solution you named.  Export to temp file, count the lines, delete the file.  A fairly expensive operation if your doing this file-by-file.  It may be better to fetch the entire repo if you need to line-count every file and reuse the working directory for future runs.

Answer (score 0):

The meta data (like current line count) is not contained within the repository but you can get the file without doing messy temp files.

For brevity, excluded code to iterate over revisions etc.

```
using (var client = new SvnClient())
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        client.Write(new SvnUriTarget(urlToFile), memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        int lineCount = 0;
        while (streamReader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
    }
}
```